# Elasticache setup for high read IO/s

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I'm considering using Amazon Elasticache but can't decide which node type to use.
I have approx 50K reads IO/s and very low writes IO/s (~500 IO/s)
my data size is around 1-3GB (very low at the moment)
I have approx 1500 concurrent clients

Which node type should I use to get max of 0.5ms latency ?